# After changing CDH5 Kerberos Authentication i am not able to access hdfs

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to implement Kerberos authentication. I am using **Hadoop 2.3** version of hadoop on **cdh5.0.1**. I have done the following changes :

- Added following properties to **core-site.xml**

  ```
  <property>
  <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
  <value>kerberos</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
  <value>true</value>
  </property>
  ```

  After restarting the daemon when i am issuing hadoop fs -ls / command, I am getting following error :

  **ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Server asks us to fall back to SIMPLE auth, but this client is configured to only allow secure connections.; Host Details : local host is: "cldx-xxxx-xxxx/xxx.xx.xx.xx"; destination host is: "cldx-xxxx-xxxx":8020;**

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance,
Ankita Singla

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot more to configuring a secure HDFS cluster than just specifying `hadoop.security.authentication` as `Kerberos`. See Configuring [Hadoop Security in CDH 5](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Security-Guide/cdh5sg_cdh5_hadoop_security.html) about the required config settings. You'll need to create appropriate keytab files. Only after you configured everything and you confirmed that none of the Hadoop services report any error in their respective logs (namenode, datanode on all hosts, resourcemanager, nodemanager on all nodes etc) can you attempt to connect.